# Find the curve through $(2,6)$ with the gradient $dy/dx = 1-4x+3x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you answer this question:

> The gradient function of a curve is given by $$dy/dx = 1-4x+3x^2$$ Find the equation of the curve given that it passes through $(2,6)$.

#### Background

I have just started this topic at school and we have done similar questions like this but they were quite simpler. So I just wanted to see the method in doing this.

Comment: What work have you done so far to answer it?

Comment: I would answer it by integrating and putting the point into the resulting equation..but that is just me.

Comment: $\int_6^ydy = \int_2^x\left(1-4x+3x^2\right)dx$...

Comment: I have just started this topic at school and we have done similar questions like this but they were quite simpler. So I just wanted to see the method in doing this.

Comment: Thankyou for all the help so far ... Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, find $$F(x) = \int (1-4x + 3x^2)\,dx = x - 2x^2 + x^3 + C$$

Then, solve for the constant of integration using $x = 2, y = 6$ in your result for  $y = F(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=C+x-2x^2+x^3$$
and
$$f(2)=C+2-8+8=6$$
so $C=4$.